# iwatch can't cp?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am creating a tool that is supposed to get data from a CD-ROM upon inserting.
This is supposed to be  headless, so I wanted to use iwatch to monitor for changes in the /media/ folder. So far it works, but as soon as iwatch calls the script for copying the files, it fails because cp can't find the files on CD.
*However*, when I use iwatch to simply echo "CD Inserted" and then manually call the script, it works without fail. So I believe the reason for the error lies somewhere between iwatch and cp.

---

My used command, which doesn't work, is:

```bsh
iwatch -c ./myscript -v -e create /media/
```

Whereas running these commands does work:

```bsh
iwatch -c "CD Inserted" -v -e create /media/
./myscript
```

But I can't start the script manually every time a CD is inserted. Is there another way to call `./myscript` automatically when the system detects a new CD?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the solution just came to me.
I simply started the script with a delay of five seconds, so the machine had time to notice the contents of the CD.